# What is the stadium curve, and how differentiable is it?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

What is the definition of a stadium curve and does it have a curvature that is defined and continuous
at each of its points?

Comment: Based on the responses below, it seems that the curvature is not defined at each point.  There are four points where the curvature has a discontinuity, namely the points where the semicircles contact the straight sides.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there exists a general definition of a stadium curve, but a Bunimovich stadium is a well-known example: It is a rectangle capped by semicircles.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards#Bunimovich_stadium

Answer (score 1):

> ... the "classical" stadium [curve] with the boundary that consists of two semicircles and two parallel segments tangent to them ...

from *Loskutov, Alexander; Ryabov, Alexei*, [**Particle dynamics in time-dependent stadium-like billiards**](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1019735313330), J. Stat. Phys. 108, No. 5–6, 995–1014 (2002). [ZBL1124.82310](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1124.82310).

It's continuous, so is its derivative, but its second derivative is (I believe) not continuous. So I'd say it was in differentiability class C^1.